# Ubuntu - Cant copy from /Downloads/ to /var/www/ with file browser

Tags: ubuntu

I download zip file that I made in Windows from Gmail to Ubuntu Downloads.
I try to copy him to `/var/www/` with file browser without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you do not have write permission to the /var/www directory - only root can write there.

You can start your file browser as root at the with the command `gksu nautilus /home/USERNAME/Downloads`.

If you do not have an open terminal handy, Alt-F2 will get you a launcher jobby.

Comment: Thamks! Can i config without involve terminal?

Comment: Do the Alt-F2 thing.  

You could create a launcher (program shurtcut) by right clicking on the desktop, and copying in the command above.  

The Dolphin file manager in KDE has an option of "Open as Superuser" on the right click menu, has nautilus got something similar (I don't often use Gnome and can't remember Nautilus having something similar)?

Comment: The right click to open a folder as superuser can be got in Ubuntu by installing the "nautilus-gksu" package.